# How to handle which tab is opened by default when loading an HTML in a WebView?

Tags: android

I want to load an HTML in a webview in my application that contains multiple tabs, something similar to this : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators

In my code I simply take to html text and load it in the webview:

```
 webView.setBackgroundColor(getColor(transparent));      
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadData(htmlContent, MIME_TYPE, null);
```

How can I handle in code so that one specific tab to be open by default when we first enter the page?

Answer (score 0):

After loading the content you can execute Javascript in the WebView like

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:openCity('Paris');");
```

or with Kitkat and up

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("openCity('Paris');", null);
```